# how to replace string then change color of string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem: how to make sure that when selecting answers, the answers will be replaced in the paragraph _ _ _ _ _ and then the text will change the color of that text. The problem is the response data. From the api, sometimes there will be a lot _ or sometimes there will be a little, so I don't know how to solve it. This is my problem and my code, thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l842.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKVs5.jpg)

```
 String targetCharacter = "_";
 widget.isChecked == true ||
                          widget.answer?.id == widget.choiceAnswer?.id
                      ? Text(widget.question?.content
                              ?.replaceFirst(
                                targetCharacter,
                                widget.question?.answers?[widget.index ?? 0]
                                        .text ??
                                    ''.trim(),
                              )
                              .replaceAll(
                                targetCharacter,
                                ''.trim(),
                              ) ??
                          '')
                      : ConvertLatex(
                          content: widget.question?.content,
                          maxLine: isShow != true ? 5 : 100,
                        ),
```

If anyone has a way to solve this problem, please help me. Thank you very much

Comment: At first glance it looks to me like your code should work correctly. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I did notice that you are just simply calling `trim()` on the empty string, that won't do much

Comment: When I click on the question, the _ _ part in the answer will be replaced, but I don't know how to change its color?

Comment: Does the full question need to become a different color, or only the filled in answer part?

Comment: hi, i just need the answer fill part

Comment: Hello, after solving the above problem, I have one more problem: how to make each time I click on each answer, each answer will correspond to each question according to each position. as above. For example, if I chose the cooking-hate answer it would be "She never COOKS. She HATES it." , I have edited the photo in the description. If you have any solutions or opinions, please help me, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this part

```
                      Text(widget.question?.content
                          ?.replaceFirst(
                            targetCharacter,
                            widget.question?.answers?[widget.index ?? 0]
                                    .text ??
                                ''.trim(),
                          )
                          .replaceAll(
                            targetCharacter,
                            ''.trim(),
                          ) ??
                      '')
```

with

```
       RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
            children: (widget.question?.content ?? '')
                .split(RegExp(r'(?<=[_])(?=[^_])|(?<=[^_])(?=[_])'))
                .map((e) => RegExp(r'_').hasMatch(e)
                    ? TextSpan(
                        text: (widget.question?.answers?[widget.index ?? 0].text ?? '').trim(),
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                      )
                    : TextSpan(
                        text: e,
                      ))
                .toList())),
```